# snscrape error - twitter scrape crashes after a long time giving '215' error

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, nlp, twitter-api-v2

I got the following error:

> https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweets=true&q=from%3Ainfobae+since%3A2018-01-01+until%3A2018-12-31&tweet_search_mode=live&count=100&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&cursor=scroll%3AthGAVUV0VFVBaCgLWNpcPlwx0WgICrnczcn_sdEnEV8PFqFYCJehgHREVGQVVMVDUBFdoJFQAA&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel

> snscrape.base:4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweets=true&q=from%3Ainfobae+since%3A2018-01-01+until%3A2018-12-31&tweet_search_mode=live&count=100&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&cursor=scroll%3AthGAVUV0VFVBaCgLWNpcPlwx0WgICrnczcn_sdEnEV8PFqFYCJehgHREVGQVVMVDUBFdoJFQAA&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel

I used this code:

```py
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd
import re

# Setting variables to be used below
maxTweets = 350000

# Creating list to append tweet data to
tweets_list1 = []
user_list = ['lanacionmas','LANACION','Ambitocom','infobae','clarincom']
# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
for user in user_list:
  for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:' + user +' since:2018-01-01 until:2018-12-31').get_items()):
    if i>maxTweets:
        break

    tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content])

print('Done' + user)
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does not appear that anyone is actively maintaining that API. The errno linux returned was ENOCEO. To fix, signup or propose a candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel like your lucky day, because I created an account here just to reply to you.

In in this [issue](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/634), the module creator explains what happened and how to solve the problem, but you just need add `top=True` in commands that have Twitter**Scraper, or if you are using it from the command line, use the flag `--top`

(I just found out that I could have posted as a guest)