# Snscrape sntwitter Error while using query and TwitterSearchScraper: "4 requests to ... failed giving up"

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

Up until this morning I successfully used snscrape to scrape twitter tweets via python.
The code looks like this:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
query = "from:annewilltalk"
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()):
     # do stuff
```

But this morning without any changes I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter.py", line 568, in <module>
    Scraper = TwitterScraper()
  File "twitter.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.get_tweets_talkshow(username = "annewilltalk")
  File "twitter.py", line 271, in get_tweets_talkshow
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snscrape/modules/twitter.py", line 1455, in get_items
    for obj in self._iter_api_data('https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json', _TwitterAPIType.V2, params, paginationParams, cursor = self._cursor):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snscrape/modules/twitter.py", line 721, in _iter_api_data
    obj = self._get_api_data(endpoint, apiType, reqParams)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snscrape/modules/twitter.py", line 691, in _get_api_data
    r = self._get(endpoint, params = params, headers = self._apiHeaders, responseOkCallback = self._check_api_response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snscrape/base.py", line 221, in _get
    return self._request('GET', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snscrape/base.py", line 217, in _request
    raise ScraperException(msg)
snscrape.base.ScraperException: 4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=from%3Aannewilltalk&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo failed, giving up.
```

I found online, that the URL encoding must not exceed a length of 500 and the one from the error message is about 800 long. Could that be the problem? Why did that change overnight?
How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snscrape error - twitter scrape crashes after a long time giving '215' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972344/snscrape-error-twitter-scrape-crashes-after-a-long-time-giving-215-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a lot of discussion in the snscrape github, but none of the answers worked for me.
I now have a workaround using the shell-client. Executing the queries via terminal works for some reason.
So I execute the shell command via subprocess, save the result in a json and load that json back to python.

Example shell command: `snscrape --jsonl --max-results 10 twitter-search "from:maybritillner" > test_twitter.json`

Answer (score 0):

the same problem here. It was working just fine and sudenly stoped. I get the same error code.
This is the code I used:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

# Creating list to append tweet data to
tweets_list2 = []

# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('xxxx since:2022-06-01 until:2022-06-30').get_items()):
if i>100000:
    break
tweets_list2.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.user.username])

# Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above
tweets_df2 = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list2, columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id', 'Text', 'Username'])
print(tweets_df2)
tweets_df2.to_csv('xxxxx.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it code you faced an error with? Or the code to fix it?
The answer shall be a solution. Once you have enough reputation you'll be able to add comment to amend a question.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter changed something that broke the snscrape requests several days back. It looks like they just reverted back to the configuration that worked about 15 minutes ago, though. If you are using the latest snscrape version, everything should be working for you now!

Here is a thread with more info:
https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/671

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your snscrape version not updated... So, we need to do that uninstall snscrape and then install latest version of snscrape... It works. I also get some error so I do above thing then I scrape Twitter tweets without error